# $\gcd(2^{2f+1}\pm 2^{f+1}+1, 2^{2f+1}-2^k)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I look for common divisors of the numbers of the form 
$\Phi_8^{’}=2^{2f+1}+2^{f+1}+1$ and $\Phi_8^{’’}=2^{2f+1}-2^{f+1}+1$ with $2^{2f+1}-2^k$. Here $f$ and $k$ are positive integers which $k$ always divides $2f+1$. I know now that if $2f+1\equiv k \mod 4$, then $\gcd(\Phi_8, 2^{2f+1}-2^k)=2^{2k}+1$, where $\Phi_8=\Phi_8^{’}\Phi_8^{’’}=2^{4f+2}+1$. Otherwise $\gcd=1$. I want to know that under the conditions $2f+1\equiv k \mod 4$ and $k>1$  with $k \mid 2f+1$, is it true that both 
$\gcd(\Phi_8^{’}, 2^{2f+1}-2^k)$
and
$\gcd(\Phi_8^{’’}, 2^{2f+1}-2^k)$
are greater than $1$? 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you tried euclidian division ?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered in Lemma 2.4 of 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.00991v1